# XML based programming language

Tags: xml

I think that html is the easiest thing to learn when you are starting to learn about web, scripting and programming. I know that html is not like real programming languages, but that's not the point of the discussion. So, wouldn't it be nice if people could script their programs in a html way, like XML?

I've searched on google for a while but i've only found a few examples like the "o:XML Programming Language" and "Superx++", but they seems to be so much theoretical.

Do you know any XML based programming language?
Do you think that's a good idea to teach these languages or start to working in them?
Do you know any tool that could help in the creation of the interpreter for these languages, like a XML parser?

Comment: "To a man with a new hammer, everything looks like a nail."  Have you looked at PHP?

Comment: ... or at .NET? or JSP? or anything else?

Answer (score 8):

XSLT is an XML based transform language, but I can't say it's very fun or easy to use.

MXAML and XAML are declarative markup commonly used for creating UI hierarchies.

I would suggest taking the time to learn another language (python perhaps?), I doubt you will ever look back.

Comment: both mxml and xaml are for data presentation, i'm searching for a xml PROGRAMMING language... and python rules

Comment: @Gabriel: he gave you one, XSLT.

Comment: XSLT, as gross as it is, is a functional functional programming language (and no, that's not a typo).

Comment: @Gabriel How about lisp. Just replace the parentheses with angle brackets.

Answer (score 3):

I don't quite see the advantage. Either something is a descriptive language (a.k.a. markup language) or it's a "real programming language", which usually means it has features like variables, `if...else` and some form of loops. XSLT is sort of in the middle but is still more descriptive than anything else. If you want to learn "real programming", I don't see the advantage of typing more code in some specialized XML syntax over any other traditional syntax.

Learning the concepts of programming is what you should be interested in, the language is just a means to express those concepts. Whether you type (hypothetically)

```
<xml:loop var="x" start-value="0" condition="<10" post="x++">
    ....
</xml:loop>
```

or

```
for (var x; x < 10; x++) {
    ....
}
```

really doesn't make that much of a difference. Actually, I prefer the shorter syntax.

Comment: I use MathCAD for my engineering work.Ability to use subscripted var names is very valuable for me. I have to include a lot of information in var name to differ one var from another.So after MathCAD I can't use other languages,even specialized like Mathematica and MatLab.Maplesoft Maple has nearly the same or even more rich naming possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Well ColdFusion is alot like XML/HTML/SGML markup... very tag based. MXML is also a tag based language and is used in conjunction with ActionScript - but i compiles to Flash (.swf)

Answer (score 2):

That XML is easy to write does not mean that it can be used to easily program in. The closest that I could see would be a programming tool that happens to use XML as a representation of the program.

Answer (score 2):

The world is full of XSLT haters, but I'm not one of them.  It's one of the most useful technologies I've learned in the last decade.

It's also got a very limited scope; while, as Michael Kay demonstrated in his *XSLT Programmer's Reference*, it's possible to implement a knight's-tour algorithm in XSLT, there's no practical reason for doing so.

Answer (score 1):

XML and the like are designed to express hierarchical data in a (relatively) succinct fashion. XML is *okay* at this, and enjoys great success.

However, most programs don't lend themselves to being expressed hierarchically. Because of this, they can't easily be expressed in XML or any similar syntax. How would you express a recursive function in XML? Wait, bad example. How would you express a reporting engine in XML?

Modern languages are more verbose because we require them to be, and the ultimate goal of any production language - that is, anything that's not a freakin' science project or grad student application - is to get things done, fast. As engineers, we are fortunate to experience the disruption where the rubber meets the road, and see what works vs what sounds cool. XML-based programming languages sound neat, but, for the most part, are inadequate. (For those that would argue: provide an XML overview of an Apollo 11 simulator, and we'll talk).

Answer (score 1):

I remember some hullabaloo about [Water](http://waterlanguage.org/) a while back.  Personally, an XML-based programming language seems like a nightmare to me.

Answer (score 1):

**XProc** isn't exactly what you want, but it might be close.  It's an **XML pipeline language**, a language for describing operations to be performed on XML documents.

From the [W3C's XProc spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xproc/):

"An XML Pipeline specifies a sequence of operations to be performed on zero or more XML documents. Pipelines generally accept zero or more XML documents as input and produce zero or more XML documents as output. Pipelines are made up of simple steps which perform atomic operations on XML documents and constructs similar to conditionals, iteration, and exception handlers which control which steps are executed."

**Pros**:  It's in XML and has some elements of a real programming language (e.g., conditions, loops).

**Cons**:  It's not a real programming language and is scoped to operate on XML documents.

Answer (score 0):

XQuery and xqib.

XQuery have the same potential as xslt--but it is still prefer to use xslt, when transforming large files--. Xqib is --was-- a project, to show that it can be use as an all prosole language. Just type xqib in google and the end extension should be .org.